# Visual Studio 2022 - Is there a way to "link" two tabs so they always view at the same time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

Example of 3 pairs of .h/.cpp I want locked together(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEzRP.png)

Basically, I like to have my .h and .cpp files open together just so I can easily reference its members. I know VS2022 has tons of functionality, so I was wondering if there was a way lock two tabs in separate windows on VS so that whenever I select either of them in there separate windows, the matching .h/.cpp will automatically be selected as well.

Briefly looked through the tab and windows options and wasn't able to dig up anything helpful.

Comment: To answer the question: no. There _might_ be an extension, but VS does not provide this on its own. If it is an extension, I don't know it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Visual Studio itself does not provide this functionality.
You can use Visual Studio's object browser instead.

Select Class View Window -> right click class -> Browse Definition.

Drag the window to one side and dock it separately

Then double click on the method to jump to the definition.
Such as

[image]